# What is the way to add an image

Tags: image, matlab

I am using this code for an image, to make the 4th quarter of it equal to zero, and then need to add a new image in that quarter but in the form of (Binary image ) what will be the way to that.

```
clc
clear all
Q=imread('E:\stuff TOO\MATLAB\2rr.jpg');  % loading the image
R=rgb2gray(Q);                            % converting to grayscale
S=imresize(R,[600 600]);  % image resized for simpilcity of dividing(optional)
T=reshape(S,600,600);     % image divided into 4 equal quarter
U=mat2cell(T,[300 300],[300 300]);        % using thereshape & mat2cell codes
U1=0.*U{2,2};             % zeroto convert the quarter into a zero matrix(100x100)
V=[U{1,1} U{1,2}; U{2,1} U1];             % rebuilding the new image(matrix)
figure,imshow(R);
figure,imshow(V);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
%%// Read in the first image and convert to gray one as done in the original code
first_img = rgb2gray(imread(FILE1)); 

%%// Read in the second image as a binary image, which will be resized and 
%%// put into the fourth quad of the first iamge
second_img = im2bw(imread(FILE2)); 

%%// Get image sizes of the first image
[m,n,c] = size(first_img);

%%// Decide on the start row and column of the fourth quad
srow = m - round(m/2)+1;
scol = n - round(n/2)+1;

%%// Finally do the overlay
output_img = first_img;
output_img(srow:end,scol:end) = imresize(255.*second_img,[round(m/2) round(n/2)]);
```

Comment: Dear Sir, I tried to do so but the rest of the image is getting black, wile in need the rest of the information to be kept at the 1st and 2nd and the 3rd quarter of the first image...

Comment: But, the fourth quad has the another image added/overlayed onto it, right?

Comment: yes that is true but still the rest of the image is wanted